# Create user using FOS user bundle for custom defined user type

Tags: php, symfony, fosuserbundle, sonata-admin

Here is what i am working on i have defined the custom user types using the FOS user bundle also using sonata admin bundle ,i have successfully created services for admin `config.yml`, Also generated the fos user entity in my custom bundle

```
sonata.admin.hrmanagement:
    class: Namespace\Mybundlename\Admin\MyAdminClass
    tags:
        - { name: sonata.admin, manager_type: orm, group: "Content", label: "My user type" }
    arguments: [null, Namespace\Mybundlename\Entity\FosUser, ~]
    calls:
        - [ setTranslationDomain, [NamespaceMybundlenameBundle]]
```

I have imported above yml in main congig.yml under app folder ,While creating the user i want the my security encoder to hash the received  plain password (creating/editing user ),successfully defined the security encoder in main security.yml like

```
security:
    encoders:
       Namespace\Mybundlename\Entity\FosUser: sha512
```

Now in `MyAdminClass` i have filters for before update and after update how can i access above defined security encoder of my entity

```
public function preUpdate($object)
{
   $salt = md5(time());
   $encoderservice = $this->get('security.encoder_factory');// here is the problem i can't access
   $encoder = $encoderservice->getEncoder($object);
   $encoded_pass = $encoder->encodePassword($object->getPassword(),$salt );             
   $object->setSalt($salt);

}
```

Comment: is `preUpdate(...)` the method you are trying to use and it's not working as expected or what is the exact problem here?

Comment: Problem is i am not able to get my defined `security.encoder_factory`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to use

`$this->getConfigurationPool()->getContainer()->get('security.encoder_factory')` as container is not directly accessible in the Admin class.

**EDIT**

If you want to have the object available directly to your code (like `$this->container` ) then you can do the following:

add a `protected $container` in your admin class

add a `configure` method in your admin class:

fetch the container, and assign it to the `$container`

```
public function configure() {
    $this->container = $this->getConfigurationPool()->getContainer();
}
```

**Profit!**

Comment: Thanks for your answer is there a way can i access container directly in my admin class ?

Comment: yes and no, container object is not directly accessible in the Admin class but i can understand your problem, fortunately there is an easy way available to do that :) i will post the code shortly